# How can I know if certain model data is bound to a view?

Tags: angularjs

My goal is to have a WebApp that presents its own desktop-like view.  Suppose I have a number of customer records (with name, address etc.) that may be displayed in a number of ways at the same time.  A given customer may be displayed in one or more lists, or on a pop-up detail view, etc.

I want to cache customer data locally as long as it's relevant, and I don't want it to ever get stale, so the server will notify my WebApp (via CometD or some mechanism) that customer id X has been changed.  So now what I want is:

1. If customer X is currently displayed anywhere on the view, re-fetch
   it from the server so that the display is updated.
2. If customer X is not currently displayed anywhere, just delete the local copy of it
   since it's stale.  It'll be re-fetched if accessed later.

So my question is, how do I detect if a given piece of data is currently bound to a view?